# How to install and start a Windows Service under NetworkService account by using WiX?

Tags: windows, installation, service, wix

I am trying to create a wix installer to install and start a Windows Service under NetworkService account, but failed, what I got is "Service"() could not be installed. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services."

Please advice, my code is as below:

```
<Component Id="service" Guid='myguid'>
          <File Id='JobServiceEXE' Name='JobService.exe' DiskId='1' Source='mypath\JobService.exe' KeyPath='yes' />
          <ServiceControl Id="JobService" Name="[SERVICEID]" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
          <ServiceInstall
          Id="JobService" Name="[SERVICEID]" DisplayName="[SERVICENAME]" Type="ownProcess"  Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" Vital ='yes'
          Account="NT Authority\NetworkService"
          Description="Job Service" />
        </Component>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the message you're getting may be due to a security issue. Your installer must be run by an administrator because creating services requires administrative privileges. You might check for that in a `Condition` element.

Second, using `NT Authority\NetworkService` as the account name will fail on non-English systems, because built-in account names are localized. Instead, use plain old `NetworkService` which Wix recognizes specially and resolves into the correct localized name.

Comment: Thank you for replying, would you please let me know how to check for the security issue in Condition element? I am pretty new to wix. I just changed the account name to NetworkService, but the result is still the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Paul's response is not correct.  As per MSDN documentation, to specify the Network Service account, use "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE":

> ...the name of the account must be
>
> `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE`
>
> when you call *CreateService* or *ChangeServiceConfig*, regardless of the locale...

Set the property "ALLUSERS" to force an Administrator install.

see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx) link for further information

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this one on Windows 7 and it was bugging me for ages. I fixed it by adding

```
InstallScope="perMachine"
```

To my package element:

```
<Package Description="..."
         Manufacturer="Microsoft Corporation"
         InstallerVersion="200"
         Languages="1033"
         Compressed="yes"
         InstallScope="perMachine"/>
```